# I am getting "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" despite not making any changes to the dictionary. How do i resolve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, topological-sort

I am trying to implement Topological Sort in Python 3.7 but am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonchallenge/topological_sort.py", line 42, in <module>
    graph_.Topological_Sort()
  File "D:/pythonchallenge/topological_sort.py", line 28, in Topological_Sort
    for node in self.adj_list:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Here is my code:

```
# Topological Sort
# Algorithm - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/

from collections import defaultdict


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.adj_list = defaultdict(list)
        self.visited = []
        self.size = size

    def Insert_Node(self, u, v):
        self.adj_list[u].append(v)

    def Topological_Sort_Util(self, input_node, input_stack):
        self.visited[input_node] = True

        for child in self.adj_list[input_node]:
            if not self.visited[child]:
                self.Topological_Sort_Util(child, input_stack)

        input_stack.append(input_node)

    def Topological_Sort(self):
        self.visited = [False] * self.size
        stack_ = []
        for node in self.adj_list:
            if not self.visited[node]:
                self.Topological_Sort_Util(node, stack_)

        while len(stack_) != 0:
            print(stack_.pop(-1), end=" ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_ = Graph(4)
    graph_.Insert_Node(1, 3)
    graph_.Insert_Node(2, 1)
    graph_.Insert_Node(4, 2)
    graph_.Insert_Node(4, 3)
    graph_.Topological_Sort()
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error despite me not making any modifications to the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **You are changing the size of the `defaultdict` by accessing a non-existing member**.

You are doing the following:

1. Loop over `self.adj_list`, which is (despite the name) a `defaultdict`
2. Call `Topological_Sort_Util` with a node from `self.adj_list` (so far so good)
3. Loop over the children in `self.adj_list[input_node]`
4. Call `Topological_Sort_Util` recursively with the children of the node

The last step is where things go wrong in your example. Node 1 has node 3 as the only child, but you never add node 3 to `adj_list`. Because `adj_list` is a `defaultdict`, the line

```
for child in self.adj_list[input_node]:
```

will add a new key for `input_node` to `adj_list` if it doesn't exist yet. This changes the size of the dictionary, and an exception is thrown.

You can see this by printing `adj_list` before and after the call to `Topological_Sort_Util`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [3], 2: [1], 4: [2, 3]})  # before
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [3], 2: [1], 4: [2, 3], 3: []})  # after
```

You can fix it by making sure the child node exists in `Insert_Node`:

```
def Insert_Node(self, u, v):
    self.adj_list[u].append(v)
    self.adj_list[v]
```

#### Another problem

Your `visited` attribute is a `list`, which uses 0-based indexing, but you start numbering your nodes from 1. So, when you do

```
self.visited[input_node] = True
```

it will fail for node 4, because your `list` only has size 4 (last index is 3).

So you either need to

- Convert `visited` to a dict with arbitrary keys or
- Make sure to make `visited` big enough to index into all of your nodes or
- Start numbering nodes from 0